# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. Integrating React-Redux problem

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Details: I want to integrate a React-Redux project into a ReactJs template but I get this error. I have tried to include applyMiddleware in my index.js but it still did not works out. I'm not really familiar in applying Middleware. Could you please help me out!

[image]

2 stack frames were collapsed.

UsersComponent.componentWillMount
src/views/Users/containers/UsersComponent/index.js:12
   9 | 
  10 | class UsersComponent extends Component {
  11 |   componentWillMount() {

> 12 |     this.props.fetchUsers();
>     13 |   }
>     14 | 
>     15 |   searchUser(username) {

Module../src/index.js
src/index.js:15
  12 | 
  13 | const store = createStore(Reducers, applyMiddleware());
  14 |

> 15 | ReactDOM.render(
>     16 | , document.getElementById('root'));
>     17 | serviceWorker.unregister();
>     18 |

Comment: Can you provide whats in fetchUsers?
It should be a plain object with type and payload

Comment: Chances are your fetchUsers does not return a plain object. Consider using redux-thunk for dispatching async action.

Comment: export function fetchUsers() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(usersRequested());

    return fetch.users().then(users => {
      dispatch(receiveUsers(users));
    });
  }
} @varoons